# Question about the name of a software design pattern was deleted

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounty, deleted-questions, automatic-deletion

My question about the name of a design pattern was deleted by "Community":

[Name of Design Pattern: get class from class level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27571848/name-of-design-pattern-get-class-from-class-level)

I can't see why this question was deleted.

Where should I ask questions like this?

Comment: Questions like this are fine on meta. Your question is undeleted by 3 users.

Comment: Something went **very** wrong here, it got auto-deleted even though the question had a bounty.  You also paid for the bounty twice, again today when it was undeleted.  This is a whopper of a bug.

Comment: @HansPassant: I didn't see he paid twice. He does have a bounty on another question though.

Comment: @HansPassant SO tells me "This question was voluntarily removed by its author" on that one. _SO could be lying though._

Comment: @KevinBrown: I wonder where you see that. The [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27571848/revisions) shows it was deleted by Community.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: That's the message that would appear on the effectively-a-404 shown to <10k users when navigating to the question while it was deleted.

Answer (score 22):

The question was automatically deleted according to [the following criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006):

> If the question is more than 30 days old, and ...
>
> has −1 or lower score has no answers is not locked ...or...
>
> it was closed and migrated to a different site ... it will be
>   automatically deleted.

So the deletion of this question happened according to the rules, but those rules completely ignore the presence of a bounty.

The deletion is not a bug, but it is surprising as bountied questions are protected against closure. They should also be protected against deletion unless a diamond moderator intervenes and refunds the bounty.

Comment: Please note this report on MSE: [Prevent questions with bounty to be auto-deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247970/245360).